# Array out of bounds error in for loop (reading excel file in Selenium Webdriver, Java)

Tags: java, selenium

This is the entire bulk of the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++, column++, row++) {
    // read cell, input coordinates: (column, row)
    Cell c1 = sh1.getCell(column, row);
    Cell c2 = sh1.getCell(column + 1, row);
    Cell c3 = sh1.getCell(column + 2, row);
    Cell c4 = sh1.getCell(column + 3, row);

    // return string content
    String locationCode = c1.getContents();
    String locationName = c2.getContents();
    String description = c3.getContents();
    String address = c4.getContents();

    driver.findElement(By.id("tab7")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("subtab2")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("new")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ExtLocationCode")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ExtLocationCode")).sendKeys(locationCode);
    driver.findElement(By.id("LocationName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("LocationName")).sendKeys(locationName);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Description")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Description")).sendKeys(description);
    driver.findElement(By.id("address1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("address1")).sendKeys(address);
    driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("actions")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
}
```

After running it, it says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

and it doesn't proceed to the next columns and rows of the cells in the excel file. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Where does the error occur? And are you reading a diagonal? Because you are increasing both row and column in each loop.

Comment: What is the structure of whatever it is you are trying to read? You seem to be trying to read more than what you have.

Comment: How many `rows` and `columns` are there in the sheet?

Comment: you should go till your data length using loop..

Comment: Why you are incrementing column++ in the loop? It assume it should be column = 0 and then column+1 and so on for next columns.

Answer (score 4):

You are incrementing your column in your for loop definition , afterwards you do:

```
Cell c1 = sh1.getCell(column,row);
Cell c2 = sh1.getCell(column+1,row);
Cell c3 = sh1.getCell(column+2,row);
Cell c4 = sh1.getCell(column+3,row);
```

I don't think you need to increment your column in the for loop definition `for(int i = 0; i<=1; i++, column++, row++)`
Unless you have a really strange excell sheet layout. Try `for(int i = 0; i<=1; i++, row++)`